# File Output node question

Tags: rendering

I want to describe an output file path in the File Output node were Blender will know a last variable in the file path is the name of the main .blend project file. This will save updating the File Output node path manually every time I incrementally save the project. Coming from Maya it was possible to do this and set off batch renders and I presume Blender will do the same if the correct syntax is in place.
Any help appreciated, thanks in advance,

Comment: Hello :). This is definitely a needed feature, but I'm afraid not currently implemented...